# Getting image url from amazon s3 bucket object

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

```
//story image to s3 bucket
    try {
        $s3->putObject([
                'Bucket' => $config['s3']['bucket'],
                'Key' => "uploads/{$name_of_uploaded_file}",
                'Body' => fopen($path_of_uploaded_file, 'rb'),
                'ACL' => 'public-read'
            ]);
        //remove the file
        unlink($path_of_uploaded_file);
    } catch(S3Exception $e){
        die("there was an error");
    }

    //retrieve image url
    $objects = $s3->getIterator('ListObjects', [
      'Bucket' => $config['s3']['bucket']
    ]);
    //put img url into variable so that it stores it into sql table
    $photoLink = $s3->getObjectUrl($config['s3']['bucket'], $objects['Key']);


if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['size'])){
        //send items to pending database

            //note already connected to db

          //inserts in pending db
          $sql = "INSERT INTO pending (id,photo,title,description,name) VALUES ('', :photo, :title, :description, :name)";
          $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql); 
          $stmt->bindParam(':title', $title);
          $stmt->bindParam(':photo', $photoLink);
          $stmt->bindParam(':description', $story);
          $stmt->bindParam(':name', $first_name);
          $stmt->execute();       
    }else {
      header('Location:index.php');
    }
```

How can I get php to pull out a url so that it stores ex: http://www.amazonaws/bucket/image.jpg into my sql database column photo?

Right now my web app gives me this error :
Cannot use object of type Aws\S3\Iterator\ListObjectsIterator as array in on line 127

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//retrieve image url
$objects = $s3->getIterator('ListObjects', [
  'Bucket' => $config['s3']['bucket']
]);
```

This isn't doing what you think it's doing.  As the method name suggests, this is getting you an iterator, not an in memory array.  This iterator is going to cover every item in the bucket, not just the file you uploaded.  Since it's an iterator, when you try to use an array access method (`$photoLink = $s3->getObjectUrl($config['s3']['bucket'], $objects['Key']);`), it blows up.

What you likely want is in the response from the putObject(), which you're currently not storing.  Something like:

```
try {
    $result = $s3->putObject([
<snip>
```

After that, you can access the URL with `$result['ObjectURL']`.  Full documentation for the return from [putObject() is on Amazon's site](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_putObject).

Comment: Thank you so much. I got it working. If anyone is having the same trouble just follow the steps above to pull  a url from an image in your bucket.